# Re-Calculate dates and amounts based on the calendar quarter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table and data like this

| amount | start date | end date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 30 | 01/02/2021 | 31/04/2021 |
| 30 | 01/05/2021 | 31/07/2021 |
| 30 | 01/08/2021 | 31/10/2021 |
| 30 | 01/11/2021 | 31/01/2022 |

I would like to re-calculate the amounts to get the following output

| amount | start date | end date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | 01/01/2021 | 31/03/2021 |
| 30 | 01/04/2021 | 31/06/2021 |
| 30 | 01/07/2021 | 31/09/2021 |
| 30 | 01/10/2021 | 31/12/2022 |
| 10 | 01/01/2022 | 31/03/2022 |

The query should re-calculate the amounts for calendar quarters. Ex. In the first row start date is 1st of Feb and the end date is 31st of Apr. to convert this amount into the first calendar quarter, (1st of Jan to 31st of March)  the calculation would be : 30/3*2 = 20

What is the most efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: Just to confirm: what are the data types for `start date` and `end date`? It will make a **huge** difference to this query if they are already date/datetime values, vs if you're stuck with a broken schema that treats these are varchar.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn those are datetime fields

Comment: Good to know :)

Comment: Do you really want to put one transaction into two different quarters? I assume that's what's happening, since you have 4 input rows and  5 output.

Comment: @Andrew yes that's the requirement

Comment: If the `Amount` had the value 20, would you go for (20/3*2) = `13.33` ?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the *simplest* way to do this is to expand the data by month and then reaggregate.  I would use a recursive CTE for this:

```
with cte as (
      select start_date, dateadd(day, 1, end_date) as end_date,
             amount / (datediff(month, start_date, end_date) + 1) as month_amount
      from t
      union all
      select dateadd(month, 1, start_date), end_date, month_amount
      from cte
      where start_date < end_date
     )
select min(start_date), eomonth(max(start_date)), sum(month_amount)
from cte
group by year(start_date), datepart(quarter, start_date);
```

Answer (score 1):

With the formulas found here: http://zarez.net/?p=2484, to get the first day of a quarter: `SELECT DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()), 0)`

and the last day of a quarter: `SELECT DATEADD (dd, -1, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) +1, 0))`

```
CREATE TABLE Q(amount DECIMAL(8,2), "start date" DATE, "end date" DATE);

INSERT INTO Q VALUES 
(30,    '2021/02/01',   '2021/04/30'),
(30,    '2021/05/01',   '2021/07/31'),
(30,    '2021/08/01',   '2021/10/30'),
(30,    '2021/11/01',   '2022/01/31');



WITH CTE AS (
   SELECT 
      [amount],
      [start date], 
      [end date],
      DATENAME(Quarter, [start date]) StartQuarter
   FROM Q
)
SELECT
   SUM(amount),
   StartDate,
   EndDate
FROM (
SELECT
   amount * (DATEDIFF(m,DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, [start date]), 0),[start date]))/3.0 as amount,
   DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, [start date]), 0)       as "StartDate",
   DATEADD (dd, -1, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, [start date]) +1, 0)) as "EndDate"
FROM CTE
UNION ALL
SELECT
   amount * (1-(DATEDIFF(m,DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, [start date]), 0),[start date]))/3.0) as amount,
   DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, [end date]), 0)       as "StartDate",
   DATEADD (dd, -1, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, [end date]) +1, 0)) as "EndDate"
FROM CTE
) x 
GROUP BY StartDate, EndDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided `calendar` is a table of quater start dates and using a tally

```
select c.d, sum(amount * 1.0 / (datediff(month,startd, endd) + 1))
from tbl
cross apply (
    select top(datediff(month,startd, endd) +1) dateadd(month, n, startd) d
    -- simple tally
    from (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) t(n)
    order by t.n
  ) t
join calendar c on year(c.d) = year(t.d) and month(t.d) between month(c.d) and month(c.d) + 2
group by c.d
```

[Db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=24d63a99dc92982b0bb29ec11617c11b)

Comment: if i have to return additional columns from table : tbl in the select, how should i do that?

Comment: Tbl is aggregated in the query. You can apply MIN, MAX, .. other aggregation to the column in question. If more complex processing is needed ask another question.